# C++ option pricing function...works fine individually but not for a range (vector) of stock prices

Tags: c++, vector

I am calculating an option price (call) by the following:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include "NormDistFunctions.h"

struct OptionData
{
    double X;
    double b;
    double r;
    double T;
    double sigma;
};

double EuroCall(OptionData o, double S);
double EuroPut(OptionData o, double S);
#endif
```

The input to EuroCall() is the OptionData o, and S (stock price). Here is my implementation.

```
#include "Global.h"
#include "EuroOption.h"
#include <boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions.hpp> // For non-member functions of distributions
#include <cmath>


double EuroCall(OptionData o, double S)
{
    double d1 = (log(S/o.X) + (o.b + (o.sigma * o.sigma) / 2) * o.T) / (o.sigma * sqrt(o.T));
    double d2 = d1 - o.sigma * sqrt(o.T);
    double callPrice = S * exp((o.b - o.r) * o.T) * N(d1) - o.X * exp(-o.r * o.T) * N(d2);
    return callPrice;
}
```

By itself this works fine, but I need to price this option for a range of stock prices. I created a global vector for these range of stock prices:

```
vector<double> MeshArray(double start, double end, double h)
{
    vector<double> mesh;
    mesh.reserve(100);
    for (double i = start; i <= end; i += h)
        mesh.push_back(i);
    return mesh;
}
```

Finally, in main() I have:

```
vector<double> MA = MeshArray(50.0, 100.0, 2.0);
    for (auto &i : MA)
        cout << EuroCall(o1,MA[i]) << " ";
```

The output should be a vector of call prices for each underlying stock price from 50, 52, 54....to 100. But my output is "0 0 0 0 0 0" etc. I would greatly appreciate anyone's advice on how to solve this problem, it has kept me up for two days straight.

Comment: I don't think this should be using the `mesh` tag.

Comment: I simplified the program and it is working: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: Thanks Steephen, what did you do, how can I see it?

Comment: @Steephen you put the wrong link

Comment: @kits what is `o1`? Can you post a [complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: o1 is an object of struct OptionData...it contains the strike/risk-free rate/time to expiry etc. The only other input it needs is the stock price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in invoking the `EuroCall` function with an element of the vector (i.e. a dereferenced iterator) and not an iterator

```
for (auto &i : MA)
    cout << EuroCall(o1,MA[i]) << " ";
```

Here `i` is an element of the vector (`std::vector<double>::value_type`), i.e. a `double`, not an iterator/index. So replace `EuroCall(o1,MA[i])` by `EuroCall(o1,i)` and you should be good to go.

Funny enough, your code compiles without warning because `MA[i]` refers to some offset in `MA` specified by the value `i`, which is out-of-bounds (could have catch this by using `MA.at(i)` instead, which throws an exception for out-of-bounds access), so you were walking in the land of undefined behaviour. That's why is good to choose a better name, such as `elem`, instead of `i`, when using range-based `for`, so when you see `MA[elem]` you realize something is not right.